# Why must a ScriptProcessorNode be connected to a destination?

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, html5-audio, web-audio-api, scriptprocessor

Consider the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LVFa6/

The ScriptProcessorNode EventHandler `process` is not called. Consider adding `processor.connect(audio.destination);` at the end, as shown in the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LVFa6/1/

The EventHandler `process` is now called as expected.

The Web Audio API specification [states that](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#ScriptProcessorNode)

> audioprocess events are only dispatched if the ScriptProcessorNode has at least one input or one output connected.

Why must the ScriptProcessorNode be connected to the audio destination for its EventHandler to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in Blink (Chrome).  If you remove the "webkit" prefix (and you should!), this code works in Firefox.

Comment: +1; this behavior does indeed seem to be contrary to the spec, which says that an input *or* an output should be sufficient.